# Access session object in Express middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my Express middleware stack:

```
var server = express()
    .use(express.cookieParser())
    .use(express.session({secret: 'Secret'}))
    .use(express.bodyParser())
    .use(function printSession(req, res, next) {
        console.log(req.session.user);
        next();
    })
    .use(express.static('./../'));
```

and here are two routes:

```
server.post('/setSession', function (req, res) {
    req.session.user = 'admin';
}

server.post('/getSession', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.session.user);
}
```

Now the session management in the route handlers work find. I can set `session.user` and it will persist for the subsequent requests in the same session, as confirmed by `getSession`. However, the middleware function `printSession` always prints `undefined`.

How can I access the populated `session` object in the middleware?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This program works fine. Before I access `/setSession`, the middleware prints `after session: undefined`. Once I GET /setSession, it prints `after session: admin`. As long as the browser you are testing with (not curl) stores and sends the session cookies, this will work as expected.

```
var express = require('express');
var server = express();
server.use(express.cookieParser());
server.use(express.session({secret: 'SEKRET'}));
server.use(function (q,r,n) {console.log('after session:', q.session.user);n();});
server.get('/', function (q,r,n) {r.send("you got slashed");});
server.get('/setSession', function (req, res) {
  console.log("logging admin in via /setSession");
  req.session.user = 'admin';
  res.send("admin logged in");
});
server.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with your settings. The following example, that is very similar to your code but uses `GET` instead `POST`, works fine for me

```
app.configure(function(){
  // ...
  app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
  app.use(express.session());

  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.session.user + ' from middleware');
    next();
  });

  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});
```

and

```
app.get('/getSession', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.session.user);
  res.send('awesome');
});

app.get('/setSession', function(req, res) {
  req.session.user = 'admin';
  res.send('done');
});
```

Now when you do the following everything works as expected

1. GET /getSession => undefined from middleware, undefined
2. GET /setSession => undefined from middleware
3. GET /getSession => admin from middleware, admin