# Better middleware chaining in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my Express configuration code:

```
var server = express()
    .use(express.cookieParser())
    .use(express.session({secret: buffer.toString('hex')}))
    .use(express.bodyParser())
    .use(express.static('./../'));

server.use(server.router);
```

It's quite annoying that the last `.use` is not chained like the rest.

How can I do full chaining of my Express middleware definitions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The express [use implementation](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L134) returns `this` every time and is thus always chainable. The chainability problem comes from your unnecessary use of `server.use(server.router)`, which is automatically done for you by express when your first non-middleware route is added via `server.get`, `server.post`, etc. This can [can be seen in the express source code here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L407), although this is a common point of confusion and problems (most of which come from doing `server.user(server.router)` at all as opposed to just letting the router go where it goes by default, which is almost always the correct place for it. So here's the forumla:

1. Properly ordered `server.use` calls to set up your middleware
2. Your specific routes with `server.get('/home')` and the other HTTP method functions
3. Any error handling, 404 middleware, etc

Express will add the router after 1 but before 2, and all will be well.

In the comments you claim if you omit the `server.router` line, you lose access to `req.session`. Sorry, but this is simply not the case. Here's an entire working express app that shows a middleware immediately before the session middleware having `req.session` undefined, and another one immediately after the session middleware having it exist.

```
    var express = require('express');
    var server = express();
    server.use(function (q,r,n) {console.log('Before cookie:', q.session);n();});
    server.use(express.cookieParser());
    server.use(function (q,r,n) {console.log('after cookie:', q.session);n();});
    server.use(express.session({secret: 'SEKRET'}));
    server.use(function (q,r,n) {console.log('after session:', q.session);n();});
    server.get('/', function (q,r,n) {r.send("you got slashed");});
    server.listen(3000);
```

Run it and you see this on the console.

```
Before cookie: undefined
after cookie: undefined
after session: { cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true } }
```

However, if you are asking why you can't use the `server` variable as a function parameter in the same statement in which it is defined, that's just how JavaScript works and has zero to do with express. You can't do this:

```
var foo = console.log(foo.bar);
```

Because `foo` is undefined until that entire statement is complete.

FWIW my opinion is that chainable code like this is dubious. It is unfriendly to debuggers and breakpoints, not supported as a first-class language feature, and isn't really saving you any characters compared to each line being unindented and `app.use(app.router)`, but so be it.

Comment: Yes, I caught that shortly after my first revision and updated.

Comment: You are confusing session handling and routing, which are largely unrelated. Here is the code where the router is automatically used: https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/application.js#L407. Any middleware that comes AFTER the session middleware will have access to `req.session`. Just make sure all your vanilla `app.use` calls come BEFORE any `app.get` or `app.post`, etc methods and you'll be fine. I think this has changed. It used to be the router was last, now the router is added just before your first `app.get/post/put/etc` call.

Comment: Hum. All my `app.use` come before any `app.get` or `app.post`. But this only defines handlers. Does it really affect ordering? Your statement "Any middleware that comes AFTER the session middleware will have access to `req.session`." is not true in my case.

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts. I didn't explain properly what I mean by "the `req.session` object doesn't get properly populated". Basically, I do have `req.session.cookie`, but any other properties such as `req.session.user` that I set in an `app.post` handler do not show up in a middleware handler. Please see my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414225/access-session-object-in-express-middleware